# How do I solve this error message: ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path?

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

I am trying to install Python Goose on my Mac (I'm running OSX 10.9.3). The first step in installing Goose is:

```
mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages goose
```

However when I run this command I get the following error message:

ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path

I researched this on the http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html page and added the following three lines to my bash_profile:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs

export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

After editing bash_profile I reloaded the startup file with the following:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

However I got the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py",
>   line 162, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py",
>   line 72, in _run_code
>       exec code in run_globals   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py",
>   line 16, in  ImportError: No module named stevedore
>   virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization
>   hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
**VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python** and that PATH is
set properly.

At this point I'm not sure what to do, If anybody has any ideas on how to proceed I would appreciate the help. Thanks, George

Answer (score 7):

I had some similar errors, but it was because I installed virtualenv with `pip --user virtualenv` *and* had `export PATH="$PATH:~/Library/Python/2.7/bin"`. Something failed to evaluate `~/`, and replacing it with `$HOME` fixed things.

Comment: This one happened to me and I was scratching my head for days. Your post, therefore, was extremely useful. After solving it, having a look at the [rules for tilde expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) made everything clear.

Comment: One of the projects we did in my operating systems class was writing a *nix shell. It made a lot of the absurd things you see in shell scripting make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 6):

The **ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path** has nothing to do with anything but **SYSTEM PATH**.

so what you need to do is find where your *virtualenv* is installed in my case it's here `~/.local/bin/virtualenv` because I installed it with ***pip*** so all you have to do is find the ***bin*** folder where ***virtualenv*** is installed and add that PATH to your system path variable. Adding
something like `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin` in your ***.bashrc or .bash_profile*** should do.

Than all you need is make your shell invoke the fresh changes.
`source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered why I was unable to get virtualenv to work. I originally installed virtualenv using easy_install. I'm not sure why but easy_install does not properly install virtualenv. I then reinstalled virtualenv using pip. The pip install was successful and I am now able to run the mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages goose command successfully. Thanks, George

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because my python was in a different location

so first go

`~ » which python
   /usr/bin/python`

then put that path in our `.bachrc` using this export e.g

`export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python`

Answer (score -3):

In my case I didn't have which installed. Once I installed which it worked.